# list box selected another list box is to be populted in javascript

Tags: javascript

currently working with java-script ...with list box the issue is am having is
i)main **list box** having a value country,state,etc if i have selected a Value country it have to populate a another listBox it contain a related value of country like india,italy,japan from this i can select any value to display my table

ii)and then i can select a **state** it have to  populate a two list box like **district and village**  so from this which district and which village by cascading i have to filter a value to display table

```
for example:

1) country is selected india,italy,china

    ----------------|
    |     india     |
    |--------------- |
2) state is selected so it have to populate a  district and village 

        district  village

         T.N       XXXXX
```

how to do this ....?

Answer (score 1):

**Option # 1**
you can use the Ajax to populate the second and third drop down list

**Option #2** 
you can store all data into the javascript array and using javascript funcation change the value of second and third drop down

Comment: as beginner i have no idea for this is it possible to show some example in javascript only

Comment: See the demo link :
http://bdhacker.sourceforge.net/javascript/countries/    
OR code example here : http://www.nullskull.com/q/10062569/javascript-country-state.aspx

Comment: k i wil try and inform ...anyway thank u

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be:

1. Create a 3-Dimensional array with the 1st dimension being country, 2nd dimension being state and 3rd dimension being village/city.
2. On selection of country, populate the remaining two lists with the corresponding values from the array

**EDIT:**

```
var arr=new Array();
arr[0]=new Array();
arr[1]=new Array();
.
.
arr[0][0]=new Array();
arr[0][1]=new Array();
.
.
arr[0][0][0]='India';
arr[1][0][0]='China';
.
.
arr[0][1][0]='TN';
arr[0][1][1]='XXXX';
.
.
```

This way you can create your 3D array. Assign them based on condition:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   if(arr[i][0][0]==country) {
       //create the list for that particular country using i
   }
```

Comment: as beginner i have no idea for this is it possible to show some example in javascript only